# Error after upgrading WP from 4.0.6 -> 4.4.2: empty value in wp_post_types['post']

Tags: posts, upgrade, labels

I’m attempting to upgrade a WP install from 4.0.6 to 4.4.2. Most of the update went swimmingly, but I’m faced with a pretty cool error message I can’t seem to figure out:

`Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /nas/content/staging/thebaffler/wp-content/themes/baffler/inc/custom-posts.php on line 216`

The error seems to be thrown by a theme file that renames the default labels WP uses for the ‘post’ type of content. What’s odd is that all the ‘post’ labels still continue to render with the settings specified in the theme file ‘custom-posts.’

Here’s a snippet of the code in question. 214 is the first line excerpted here. If I comment line 216, the error message refers to 215 instead:

```
$labels = &$wp_post_types['post']->labels;
$labels->name = 'Blog';
$labels->singular_name = 'Blog';
$labels->add_new = 'Add Blog entry';
$labels->add_new_item = 'Add Blog entry';
$labels->edit_item = 'Edit Blog entry';
$labels->new_item = 'Blog entry';
$labels->view_item = 'View Blog entry';
$labels->search_items = 'Search Blog Entries';
$labels->not_found = 'No Blog entries found';
$labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No Blog entries found in Trash';
$labels->all_items = 'All Blog Entries';
$labels->menu_name = 'Blog';
$labels->name_admin_bar = 'Blog';
```

Looking in the codex, I don't see any recent changes to `wp_post_types`. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_object

What should I do next to troubleshoot this error?

Thanks
James

Comment: such question that require access to your local code are off-topic. it doesn't make any sense for that value to be null, so there is probably something else that happens there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What that error is saying is that `$labels` is an empty object, so it can't assign to it.

```
$foo = NULL;
$foo->labels = false; // This causes the error
```

See this Stack Overflow post for technical details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php

Comment: Thanks Mike! I might have been vague with my question. I get that `$labels` is empty, but I can't figure out why. `$wp_post_types` hasn't changed from WP 4.0 to 4.4—why can't I set `$labels = &$wp_post_types['post']->labels;`? What's more—the labels DO still get relabeled.

Comment: `$labels = &$wp_post_types['post']->labels;`
This line is roughly equivalent to: `$labels = NULL;` You can still create attributes (or whatever the correct PHP terminology for `->` is).

Comment: Ugh. I was editing that last comment too much, apparently. But it makes sense the code works. There's nothing in `->labels` so it creates an empty object for you. Then you can add attributes. And because `$labels` is a reference, it creates that object in `$wp_post_types['post']`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I got you. I fixed the issue adding a reference to the global var `$wp_post_types` — I wonder what changed from 4.0 to 4.4 that necessitates that!